# Which approach is recommended : aggregateRoot.Items.Add(...) or aggregateRoot.AddItem(...)

Tags: c#, collections, domain-driven-design

Which approach is recommended **in a DDD world**... and why ?

1. `aggregateRoot.Items.Add(...)`
2. `aggregateRoot.AddItem(...)`

I think the first option is better since it is more related to the **ubiquitous language**.

Should I expose a readonly (IEnumerable) collection and some AddItem()/RemoveItem()/etc on the aggregateRoot (option 1) or expose a strongly typed collection (I don't like exposing IList< T > or even worst, List< T >) that supports adding/removing/etc (option 2).

Comment: womp didn't suggest that but you. He just gave some reasons why one option would be better than other. For me it seems - you are looking for problems where they do not exist.

Comment: Your right, I'll edit my post by removing that womp suggested option 2. About looking for problems where they do not exist, I think that's just like, your opinion man...

Comment: Sure it is. I didn't try to be offensive or something. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have their uses, depending on what kind of API that you want to present to your user.

If you're encapsulating a collection that you don't want users directly accessing, then you could use AddItem() as a fairly self-discoverable method to assist users in adding an item to it.

If your object exposes the collection as-is, then Items.Add() is consistent collection behaviour and would likely be the best choice.

Comment: Yes, you may be right... but I wanted an answer in terms of DDD and ubiquitous language. That is the reason I wrote aggreagteRoot. I'll edit my question to be clearer and I'll still vote your answer up.